# How to make cp command quiet when no file is found in Bash?

Tags: bash, cp

I searched `man cp`, but can find no quiet option, so that `cp` does not report "No such file or directory".

How can I make `cp` not print this error if it attempts, but fails, to copy the file?

Answer (score 58):

Well everyone has suggested that redirecting to `/dev/null` would prevent you from seeing the error, but here is another way. Test if the file exists and if it does, execute the `cp` command.

```
[[ -e f.txt ]] && cp f.txt ff.txt
```

In this case, if the first test fails, then `cp` will never run and hence no error.

Comment: However, `cp` may still throw other kinds of errors in this case, e.g. access denied. (It is a great solution if you want to suppress *only* not-found errors).

Comment: @nneonneo: ... aside from the race condition

Comment: @rici: yeah, yeah, there's a race condition. It's also still possible for it to report not-found if the destination doesn't exist. It isn't foolproof, but it is better if you only want to suppress one kind of error.

Comment: Thanks guys, valid points! Have up-voted so that OP gets a look at it before deciding on the answer.

Comment: Very strictly spoken this is not what the OP asked for, as the question was not how to call `cp` only when the source exists, but how to suppress the error message.

Comment: @rici: can you explain why there is a race condition here?

Comment: @tc88: another process could delete the file, which might take place between the test and the action. On Unix, it is not a problem if the file  is deleted during the copy, because the file's contents are not removed as long as the file is in use, so the "test before using" idiom creates a race condition. This is a common mistake. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use

Answer (score 30):

If you want to suppress just the error messages:

```
cp original.txt copy.txt 2>/dev/null
```

If you want to suppress bot the error messages and the exit code use:

```
cp original.txt copy.txt 2>/dev/null || :
```

Comment: Can you explain the colon at the end?

Comment: The `:` command is a shell builtin equivalent to the `true` command, a no-op that just returns success, i.e., returns 0. In this context it basically says "execute the copy, or, if fails, execute `:`", wich always succeed, making the whole command always succeed.

Answer (score 8):

The general solution is to redirect stderr to the bit bucket:

```
 cp old_file new_file 2>>/dev/null
```

Doing so will hide any bugs in your script, which means that it will silently fail in various circumstances. I use `>>` rather than `>` in the redirect in case it's necessary to use a log file instead.

Answer (score 3):

Like for any error printed to [STDERR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stderr#Standard_error_.28stderr.29), just redirect it to `/dev/null`:

```
cp a b 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 3):

```
rsync -avzh --ignore-missing-args /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

`ignore-missing-args`: errors ignored are those related to source files not existing

Comment: +1 This is voted down, but rsync --ignore-missing-args does exactly what I wanted it to do that brought me to this question: recursive copy, ignoring missing source files.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect:

```
cp ... 2>/dev/null
```