# GitLab pipeline - Copy file if exists

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, cp

I have a pipeline that needs to copy some files from a folder to a new one only if the files exists in the source folder.

This is my script line:

```bash
script:
    - cp source_folder/file.txt dest_folder/ 2>/dev/null
```

I have also tried this:

```bash
script:
    - test -f source_folder/file.txt && cp source_folder/file.txt dest_folder/ 2>/dev/null
```

but still fails if the file do not exists.

> Cleaning up project directory and file based variables.
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

How can I check the file and copy it only if exists?

EDIT:
this command is executed on a server, the pipeline use ssh to log into

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of the file (-f) and, in positive case, copy it.

```bash
script:
  - |
    files=(conf.yaml log.txt)

    for file in $files; do
      if [[ -f "source_folder/$file" ]]; then
        cp source_folder/$file dest_folder
      fi
    done
```

Take a look at [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337405/how-to-make-cp-command-quiet-when-no-file-is-found-in-bash) for one-shot less-flexible statements.

*Note: I haven't tested the script above, but I'm quite accustomed with Gitlab pipeline and bash.*

Comment: Hi Davide, thanks for the message. I've tried the code and edited in this way the cp row: `ssh christian@$SERVER_IP "cd ~/$SITE_FOLDER; cp public/$file temp/"` but it does not copy the file and no error is shown

Comment: I have a doubt: should the destination folder be `temp` (which means `./temp`) or should it be `/temp`?

Comment: `temp` is at the same level of public so maybe I should use `./temp`

Comment: Try to do it manually with the same bunch of commands: first try to access the server with cli (if possible), then try to use ssh (still manually).

Comment: I can access the server with ssh and cli, the pipeline runs different commands before this one on the server.  I have tried to run `cp public/conf.yml temp` and it copy the file